# How to avoid XCopy run into the error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process?

Tags: windows, xcopy

I am xcopying data from my local directory to a shared windows drive.  Once in a while i get an issue where in the middle of copying i see the following error:

**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Waiting 30 seconds . . .**

Is there any way to force an overwrite as I can't figure out how to deal with this situation once it happens.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Could you try using [HobyCopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hobocopy/) instead?  It is a SourceForge project.  Its description from there:

> HoboCopy is a backup/copy tool. It is inspired by robocopy in both
>   name and in functionality. It uses the Volume Shadow Service (VSS) to
>   "snapshot" the disk before copying. It then copies from the snapshot
>   rather than the "live" disk.

This should prevent any issues with locked / in-use files.  This does assume that VSS is enabled ("Previous Versions") for the volume you're trying to copy from.

Some additional details about VSS are available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy.

You can also find a number of tools that can be used to script VSS operations, including mounting to a drive letter / NTFS path, such that normal non-VSS-aware tools e.g. XCopy can still be used.

Alternatively, if you open the properties for a VSS-enabled drive, you should be able to use the "Open" option from the "Previous Versions" tab, and see a URL like `\\localhost\C$\@GMT-2011.12.29-04.10.15`.  This URL may also possibly be useable by XCopy and other non-vSS-aware tools.